# Nesting AND NOT ISBLANK with MULTIPLE IFs

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I can't find an example close enough to this one on StackOverflow so here goes:

I want to return a message "Type?" if cell X is blank and cell Y has any text.  But I'm trying to nestle it into an existing set of IFs.

Existing :

```
=IF($G241="Evo";M241*L241;IF($G241="Free";M241*L241;IF($G241="GN";M241*L241))))
```

Nestling this into the above:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($J234));ISBLANK(G234));"Type?";"OK")
```

I tried this but it returns FALSE, maybe due to the AND I'm using, which I need since I'm creating a return based on two cells two cells.

```
=IF($G240="Evo";M240*L240;IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($J240));ISBLANK(G240);"Type?";"OK");IF($G240="Free";M240*L240;IF($G240="GN";M240*L240))))
```

getting Error:

> AND expects boolean values. But 'Type?' is a text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.

Comment: When you say any text, Did you mean letters, or if the number 10 was in cell Y does that also get considered as text? is cell X in column J or column G?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF(and(isblank(cell x),iferror(isstring(cell y),false)),"Type?","OK")
```

That should do it for you I think.  you will need to replace cell x and cell y with the appropriate references.  The iferror statement is there to catch what happens when evaluating a blank cell y.

The problem with this formula

```
=IF($G240="Evo";M240*L240;IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($J240));ISBLANK(G240);"Type?";"OK");IF($G240="Free";M240*L240;IF($G240="GN";M240*L240))))
```

is you are trying to check G240 for different values when it cant.  Lets simplify your formula.  We will replace your empty cell check with `FORMULA 1`

```
=If($G240="EVO", Do True Condition, Do Formula 1, IF(G$240=Free, Do Free True Condition, Do Free False Condition)
```

The problem is since you already did something (Formula 1) when G240 = "EVO", you cant start another check on what G240 after the fact with the way you have embedded your formula.    a batter way of thinking of it is how to do a second check when G240="EVO" is false.  Remember the general format of an if statement is:

```
IF(CONDITION,True Result, False Result)
```

There are only 3 things that go into an if statement.  you tried putting in 3.

Try rearranging to this:

```
    =If($G240="EVO", Do True Condition, IF(SOME CHECK to determine DO FOMULA 1 or CHECK for G240 = FREE, Do Formula 1, IF(G$240=Free, Do Free True Condition, Do Free False Condition)))
```

Basically break down what you want to check for in G240 and do it in sequence with your IF statement.  Right now with what you have written, I cant tell how you want to determine if you want to run your formula 1 or if you want to check if G240="free" since you have two different outcomes if G240="Free"/

Comment: I strongly recommend against using ISBLANK().  a blank cell and a cell contain "" or a space all display the same.  "" or a space however are not blank cells.  instead of using isblank I would usually use a check something like `if(A1="", TRUE,FALSE)` or maybe even `IF(TRIM(A1)="", TRUE, FALSE)` and replace the true/false portions with the action I would do in thos cases.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think i found the issue.  The IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK works on it's own since there are no other IFs in the formula.  I do want to test two different cells for text(letters) in order to show a warning if one cell was blank while the other not.  But as soon as you insert the (AND into a string of multiple IFs it doesn't work.
Simply removing the (AND was all I needed to do.  Another way to achieve a test for more than one blank cell was to simply add multiple IF(ISBLANKs.
EG: =IF(ISBLANK(A1)+IF(ISBLANK(A2)>2;condition true;condition false)

ForwardEd thanks very much for your help!
Regards